# How to Default Subdirectories to Allow from All, While Allowing Access to Home Page in Apache

Tags: apache, httpd.conf

How do you set httpd.conf so that subdirecties are not accessable by default, and still allow public access to the home page at /index.html?

My objective is to block access to subdirectories, except for members of my development team, but still let the public see the home page at /index.html

Here is what I have in httpd.conf.  It protects subdirectries, but no one can see the home page in the root directory.

```
<Directory /path/to/home*>
    Order deny,allow
    Deny from all
</Directory>

<Directory /path/to/home/subdirectory-for-dev*>
    Order deny,allow
    Deny from all
    allow from 111.222.333.444 #developer 1's ip
    allow from 222.222.333.444 #developer 2's ip
    #etc.. for other developers
</Directory>
```

Answer (score 0):

I will suggest you please try to create .htaccess file in your subdirecties   with the following code and check it again.

```
<FilesMatch "\.(html|htm|txt|jpg|jpeg)$">
Allow from 111.222.333.444
Allow from trustedsite.com
Deny from all
</FilesMatch>
```